# Is there a verb for "to make something Spanish"?

Tags: meaning, verbs

I'm not entirely clear how you would describe a verb that fulfils this function. I'm looking for a word equivalent to "gallicise", "americanise" or "hellenise", but for Spain equivalent. Is there such a word? What morpheme would you use for Spain?

Comment: .....conquistar

Comment: Not a Spanish verb, an English verb....

Comment: .....perdoname!

Comment: You're not helping! :P

Comment: The Spanish are looking to make Gibraltar Spanish. I don't think 'Hispanicise' works here.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The word is Hispanicize (or ise, for british spelling) http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Hispanicize